# Should I move huge non text data from Elastic Search to MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I have a record structure about published news. I have a stat data for each news which contains a list of last 100 hours info like this:

```
{
facebook: 1000,
linkedin: 2000,
gplus: 500,
date: 2014-07-15
}
```

Currently I've stored these data inside my elastic search documents. Should I move them to MongoDb? Does it affect my search performance? I think since Elastic search is a specialized for full text search, It's not a good idea to store such this structure.
Please note that above structure is updated hourly for 100 hours. after this period we have a 'data' fields containing a list of 100 dictionary like this structure.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch not only aims at full text search but also on wide range of analytical computations using facets and aggregations. I have no doubts on the performance issues in elasticsearch as compared to mongoDB in terms of search and computations. The only thing it matters is the indexing time for individual documents. If you plan up any aggregation computations over these data then you better save them in elasticsearch alone.

Comment: what about the situation which this structure needs to update frequently? Is it still good to keep it in Elastic?

Comment: can you elaborate what structure you meant? if its about adding a new field then, there wont be an issue as such. But as to change the mapping on existing field then you might have to re-index every time.